# GNU Octave in rbash shell

Tags: bash, octave

I would like to start an octave session within a restricted bash shell, or rbash, and thus restrict a user to their home directory.

The rbash works as expected, and the user is unable to use the cd command.

```
>prompt:~/$ /bin/bash -r
>bash-3.2$ pwd
  /home/user1
>bash-3.2$ cd /
>bash: cd: restricted
>bash-3.2$
```

When octave is started, the user is then able to cd to any directory.

```
>bash-3.2$ octave --silent
octave-3.4.0:1> pwd
   ans = /home/user1
octave-3.4.0:2> cd /
octave-3.4.0:3> pwd
   ans = /
```

Is there a way to disable the user account within octave in the way that rbash does?

Thanks.

Comment: Tried to answer, but then realized I misread your question. It seems that you have exposed a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably a chroot-environment for Octave ([chroot(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot) / [chroot(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot)) for your Octave sub-process to isolate users from accessing real `/`.

Alternatively, you can replace the libc Octave is linked against with one that restricts the `chdir(2)` library call to directories that are allowed (see [LD_PRELOAD](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so)).

Comment: I have octave in a chrooted environment. I would like the octave prompt to respect the rbash. I will look into your second suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this may be the only way. I'll keep looking though, it doesn't seem ideal.